# TCP client in MAC using C++

Tags: macos, sockets

I am trying to write a C++ code for the client part of tcp socket to send data to server written in nodejs. I could achieve it on Windows platform, however doing the same on MAC OS is proving tough, any help/code in C++ for the client tcp socket for MAC OS is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the linux/unix libraries for the same and worked like a charm on the MAC...

this link has the info :: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know what area you are finding trouble with, perhaps the best suggestion is to use a platform independent C++ library so that the only requirement you have for making it work on a Mac and windows is to recompile it.

I am not sure what is out there, but I did find this one : http://dlib.net/